# How to tell if an ipv4 address is public or private?

Tags: ipv4, network, networking, ip-address

I've read the below thing, in a website.

> According to standards set forth in Internet Engineering Task Force
> (IETF) document RFC-1918 , the following IPv4 address ranges are
> reserved by the IANA for private internets, and are not publicly
> routable on the global internet:
>
> ```
> 10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
> 172.16.0.0/12 IP addresses: 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
> 192.168.0.0/16 IP addresses: 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
> ```

My doubt is

1. Should private addresses be only from the above mentioned ip range or can they have any ip address range?
2. Can public ip address be from the above mentioned ip addresses ? If so then will that be valid in the internet?
3. Can I tell 100% by looking at the ip address as they're private if they fall in the above ip address range?

Comment: RFC 1918 defines the Private address ranges, but there are other ranges that ate not globally routable, and others that are not routable at all. See the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Yes, to do things properly you should only use IP addresses within those 3 networks as private addresses.

2 - No, those addresses are not routable on the Internet, any decent internet service provider (ISP) will drop any packet that has one of this addresses as either source or destination.

3 - yes.

You can read the whole RFC1918 [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) (it is short).